# Is there a way to use an SVG image in Cassiopeia

Tags: templates, images, cassiopeia

I'm using Cassiopeia and Joomla 4.  I've adapted it very slightly to get to what I need but I really want to use a much smaller image size by using an SVG.

Is there any way to do this?  Previously you could just type in the correct image address but it doesn't allow you to do that in Joomla 4.

[image: Joomla 4 Cassiopeia logo input]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you figure it out yet. Hopefully you did, But just in case for other to want the answer. In Joomla 4 you have tod, in the media manager add "svg" to supported file extensions and "image/svg+xml" to the allowed mime types both without the quotes because by default Joomla 4 doesn't enable this.
SIDE NOTE: If you want your svg to fit ok use the same size and same viewbox as the default svg logo of cassiopeia. You can also use a multiple of this size (same ratio).

Comment: When I do this I get `/undefined#joomlaImage://local-images/brand-assets/lovelaser_logo_sr.svg?width=0&height=0` as the logo url

Comment: Woah that must have been a glitch somehow.  I did it again and it works.  But now I see `images/brand-assets/lovelaser_logo_sr.svg#joomlaImage://local-images/brand-assets/lovelaser_logo_sr.svg?width=0&height=0`

Comment: I'll report it as a bug

Comment: Hi @Eoin Happy that it was useful to you and hopefully for other SO users.

Answer (score 1):

The media manager does not handle svg images by default and they do carry security issues. You can upload an svg to your images folder by some other method and then you can use the image url with the Insert / Image editor button.

Comment: They don't always carry security issues.  They just have the potential to.  Which to me doesn't make sense as PHP also has that potential and we make overrides remarkably easy to use in Joomla.  If I use your method there's no way to add it to the brand "position" because it's not a position.  So I guess I need to add a new module position there and hide the brand position.  Kind of annoying to have to redo all the styling.